# single list comprehension to unpack nested dictionary

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'd like to turn this

```
a = {'a': {'b': 'b aw', 'c': 'c aw'}, 'b': {'b': 'b2 aw', 'c': 'c2 aw'}, 'c': {}}
```

into this

```
['b aw', 'c aw', 'b2 aw', 'c2 aw']
```

with a list comprehension. I think I need some way to make this expression 'legal':

```
a2 = [a1 for a1 in a.values().values()]
```

I don't want `dict(a.values)` because that will just get me back to my original dictionary, a. I know there are many ways to do this with a for loop, but is there a way to do this without a for loop? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to loop over the values of the values of your dict :

```
>>> [i for j in a.values() for i in j.values()]
['c aw', 'b aw', 'c2 aw', 'b2 aw']
```

Comment: Used it to unpack a nested dict. trigger =
{'yellow': {'next': '1/5/160', 'tomorrow': '1/5/161', 'today': '1/5/162'}, 'blue': {'next': '1/5/163', 'tomorrow': '1/5/164', 'today': '1/5/165'}, 'green': {'next': '1/5/166', 'tomorrow': '1/5/167', 'today': '1/5/168'}, 'black': {'next': '1/5/169', 'tomorrow': '1/5/170', 'today': '1/5/171'}}.
**{i:0 for j in trigger.values() for i in j.values()}** gave me my wanted output of:
`{'1/5/160': 0, '1/5/161': 0, '1/5/162': 0, '1/5/163': 0, '1/5/164': 0, '1/5/165': 0, '1/5/166': 0, '1/5/167': 0, '1/5/168': 0, '1/5/169': 0, '1/5/170': 0, '1/5/171': 0}`

Answer (score 2):

The way to make your original `values` expression

```
[a1 for a1 in a.values().values()]
```

legal, is like so:

```
import itertools

itertools.chain.from_iterable([v.values() for v in a.values()])
```

Explanation: the internal list is a list of lists - the values corresponding to each of the values. `itertools.chain.from_iterable` flattens it.

Comment: thanks for this suggestion. I need to get more familiar with itertools.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
a = {'a': {'b': 'b aw', 'c': 'c aw'}, 'b': {'b': 'b2 aw', 'c': 'c2 aw'}, 'c': {}}    
a2 = [a1 for a1 in a.values()]
a3 = [a3.values() for a3 in a2]
a3.sort()
```